# Unable to add share to 2012 R2 file server cluster - Role name not found

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, cluster, failovercluster, file-server, windows-cluster

I am trying to set up a proof of concept file server cluster to ensure it will meet our needs before we implement a live cluster.

I have setup a cluster of two nodes, with 2 networks (one for cluster and client (10.0.0.0), the other cluster only (10.1.0.0)), and the cluster runs 2 roles (SOFS and normal FS).

The roles have static IPs set on the 10.0.0.0 network which is where my client machine resides.

The SOFS role seems fine, as I can create shares, browse them and add/remove files from them. The normal FS role however, when I try to add a file share, I get an error message as per the below screenshot.

As you can see, the static IP is returned when I ping the role name from my client machine. I also did an ipconfig /flushdns on both nodes in case that is where the issue lies.

[image: Cluster Screenie]

Is this suggesting a DNS issue? I can't understand why it would be the case given the DNS entries look to be correct for that role name and provide the IP that it has been assigned within the role settings.

[image: DNS]